# Bootstrap Date Time Picker Not Working With Angular 6 or 7

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I create a normal reactive from in angular 6

```html
<div class="input-group date">
    <input type="text" class="form-control m-input m_datetimepicker"  placeholder="Select auction start date & time" 
        formControlName="addStartDate" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': addForm.get('addStartDate').touched && addForm.get('addStartDate').invalid }" />
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="la la-calendar-check-o glyphicon-th"></i></span>
    </div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
        <div>* Time start date & time is required</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So in that, I use basic jquery for initialising the date time picker

```js
$("body").on("focus", ".m_datetimepicker", function () {
    $(".m_datetimepicker").datetimepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        todayBtn: true,
        keepOpen: false,
        startDate: today,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    });
});
```

it works but when we use in form date time come but `this.addForm.value` that column means date time picker value did not bind with that `formControlName`,
it gives me `null` value. Can someone tell me why?

Comment: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use jQuery and jQuery-based libraries with Angular. It's the contradition of whole Angular idea. You also should not operate directly on DOM to stay compliant with different environments Angular serve.

To safely operate on DOM tree use built-in renderer - Renderer2 (has to be injected into component)

Try to use ngx-bootstrap library instead. It's exactly tailored for usage with Angular: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-bootstrap

**EDIT**
Here is the example of usage datepicker with ngx-bootstrap:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-datepicker

Comment: Thank You @magos for your answer. Can you tell me how can integrate time picker means Date Time Picker?